# AngularJS - How to get innerHTML of rendered DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, render

Is there any way to get innerHTML code of rendered element that includes ng-repeat loop?

For example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div ng-repeat="e in ctrl.elements>{{e.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use directive

Comment: BTW it should be [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), not `ng-for`

Comment: @barbsan Right, sorry

Comment: you probably want to look at transclusion functions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$document[0].getElementById("container").innerHTML`. 
 Remember to call it after `ng-repeat`'s job is done - I've delayed it in snippet below.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ExampleController',  function($scope, $document, $timeout) {
    $scope.ctrlelements = [{name: "aaaa"}, {name: "bbbb"}];
    
    console.log($document[0].getElementById("container").innerHTML)
    
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log($document[0].getElementById("container").innerHTML)
    }, 1000)
    });
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div id="container">
    <p ng-repeat="e in ctrlelements track by $index">{{e.name}}</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
```

PS. There may be some better way to solve your problem than dealing with `innerHTML`